# How to authenticate in UIWebView to show html files

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I have to show a html file on `UIWebView`, but reading that file from server needs authentication, I had made a NSURLRequest to load that url in `UIWebView`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: what kind of authentication is required?

Comment: basic auth? and only for the html or also for the other files

Answer (score 0):

Since i need authentication which is allready done in app so using cache data to do authentication-

NSURLRequest  *pdfLoadRequest =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.pdfURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0];